# 'New' and 'Create' RESTful action names or 'Create' for both in ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

The rails convention is to use **New** and **Create** for RESTful action names. The .NET MVC convention appears to be to use **Create** for both (usually with a post restrictor on the action intended to the true 'Create' method).

Personally I would prefer to use **New** and **Create** in .net but have been using **Create** for both given the convention. What (if any) is the benefit of the .NET MVC convention of using **Create** for both actions?

The same goes for **Edit** and **Update**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One benefit is that you can write code like:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
```

... instead of code like:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(new RouteValueDictionary{ "action", "Update" })) { %>
```

Similarly for error handling:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

... instead of:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View("Edit", model);
}
```

MVC's convention is that related stuff is named the same, not that your actions must have certain names.

Comment: This information is good. It's not just form but has functional value as well. (Though I've been doing return View("Edit", model) anyway as I believe that you cannot test the destination view name without explicitly declaring it ... I could be wrong).

Comment: Sure you can test it. You just test it to equal string.Empty, which, in MVC, means "the same as the action name, whatever that is."